# With an iOS 17 "popup type" UIButton, how to set the selected item in code?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiaction

Say you have a popup-type button,

[image]

```
@IBOutlet var popupButton: UIButton!
let xx = ["Horse","Dog","Cat","Budgie"]
let opts = xx.map({ fn in
    return UIAction(title: fn) { [weak self] _ in
        self?. ...
    }
})
opts[2].state = .on
popupButton.menu = UIMenu(children: opts)
```

[image]

During construction, you can set the selected item in the manner shown, even that is a bit hokey.

During running of the app, how the heck do you change the selected item, from code?

Unfortunately the only way I know how is use an extension like this, which is hardly elegant:

```
// Don't do this. See solution found later in the answer
let temp: [UIAction] = thePopupButton.menu!.children as! [UIAction]
temp[3].state = .on
thePopupButton.menu = UIMenu(children: temp)
// Don't do this. See solution found later in the answer
```

Surely there's some way to change the selected item on a popup UIButton? Does anyone know?

Please, please, note that this question has absolutely nothing to do with action sheets or alert controllers. Look at the first image if you're unfamiliar with the new UIButton possibilities.

Comment: Are you using the storyboard or are you creating the menu programmatically?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69815615/5133585), you'd just *have* to loop through the menu's children and set the `state`.

Comment: resolved tyhanks to @Sweeper, see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the tip by @sweeper, in fact this does seem to work OK.

Thoroughly tested:

```
///Util for the "popup" type of UIButton
extension UIButton {
    
    ///For the "popup" type buttons (iOS 14+), set the selected item.
    ///If the button is the wrong type or it's not possible, nothing is done.
    func forceSelectedIndex(_ index: Int) {
            guard (self.menu != nil) else {
                return print("forceSelectedIndex impossible")
            }
            guard index > 0 && index < self.menu!.children.count else {
                return print("forceSelectedIndex impossible")
            }
            (self.menu!.children[index] as? UIAction)?.state = .on
    }
}
```

I guess that's about all there is to it.

**No need** to copy as in my thought example in the question.

Comment: good call @Sweeper done

Comment: Why do you use `guard (self.menu != nil)` instead of `guard let menu = self.menu`? It would remove the need to forcefully unwrap it several times later in the code (`self.menu!`)

Comment: Also, instead of checking `index` being greater than 0 and lesser than `count`, it would be easier just to check if [`children.indicies`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/indices-9kkbf) contain the index.

Comment: @user28434'mstep it's a case where you have to access the original. try it the other way, it won't work

Comment: "it's a case where you have to access the original." — is `menu` not an object/of reference type? Pretty sure you will have access to the original if it is of reference type. Because it would be just another reference to the original.

Comment: What? I haven't wrote anything here for almost fortnight. What have you "literally just typed"?

Comment: lol sorry mate editing comments can be confusing on these sites! cheers.  (it meant "literally just above)