# How to set a value for PopupButton intern element in Swift

Tags: swift

I was using a UIButton on my app to show a list of options the user

This is the code used:

```
@IBOutlet weak var accountTypePopUpButton: UIButton!

accountTypePopUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
    UIAction(title: "option 1", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "option 2", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "option 3", handler: optionClosure),
    UIAction(title: "option 4", handler: optionClosure),
])
```

This is how it shows in my app.

[image: https://i.snipboard.io/prO40b.jpg]

The "option 1" is the default option that shows in the app. But I need to show "option 3" by default.

How can I change this without change the order of these options are showed to the user?

There is some type of function in "accountTypePopUpButton.menu" that I can call to achieve this ?

Example: accountTypePopUpButton.menu.setIndex(3) or accountTypePopUpButton.menu.setValue = "option 3"

Comment: Are you asking how to change which menu item has the checkmark next it by default? If so, look at the `state` parameter for the `UIAction` initializer.

Comment: No. i want to know how to change the item that was showed when I ckick in one of the options. I was searching on Google now. The correct element is a Popup button, available on iOS 14 or later. I edited the title.

Comment: Did you at least try HangarRash's suggestion? Using `UIAction(title: "option 3", state: .on, handler: optionClosure)` changes the default selected option to option 3.

Comment: If you want to *change* the selection programmatically (as opposed to setting the default option), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77827943/5133585

Comment: Both solutions above works for me. I'll use both on my app on different parts of it. Thank you Sweeper and @HangerRush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use the solution that I find in another post.

```
///Util for the "popup" type of UIButton
extension UIButton {

///For the "popup" type buttons (iOS 14+), set the selected item.
///If the button is the wrong type or it's not possible, nothing is done.
func forceSelectedIndex(_ index: Int) {
        guard (self.menu != nil) else {
            return print("forceSelectedIndex impossible")
        }
        guard index > 0 && index < self.menu!.children.count else {
            return print("forceSelectedIndex impossible")
        }
        (self.menu!.children[index] as? UIAction)?.state = .on
  }
}
```

If I try to use "forceSelectedIndex(0)", it didn't work for the index 0 when I try to change it programatically. Because of this problem, I create the code below to use a index 0

```
func selectFirst() {
    guard (self.menu != nil) else {
        return print("forceSelectedIndex impossible")
    }
    let action = menu!.children.first as? UIAction
    action?.state = .on
}
```

The code below was a suggestion from @Sweeper and it works too.

```
UIAction(title: "option 3", state: .on, handler: optionClosure)
```

There is another code that I use to get the index by name inside a UIMenu object

```
func getPopupMenuIndexByString(_ title: String, _ menu: UIMenu) -> Int {
    
    var index = 0
    var specificValue = 0
    
    menu.children.forEach { action in
        guard let action = action as? UIAction else {
            return
        }
        if action.title == title {
            specificValue = index
            return
        }
        index = index + 1
    }
        
    return specificValue
}
```